# Cannot assign value of type 'DataModel' to type 'String?' in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
{

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


var madhu = [DataModel]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
   
    download{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
   


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return madhu.count
}
   
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
   {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = madhu[row]// here i got error "Cannot assign value of type 'DataModel' to type 'String?'"
    return cell
       
   }
}
```

i am doing json decoder program i retrieved data from json and trying to keep it in table view.i got error like that.please sort out this

Comment: share your model `DataModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
cell.textLabel?.text = madhu[row].title  // e.x title
```

where `title` is the name of a property inside your model of type String

Comment: struct DataModel : Decodable
{
    let name : String
    let img  : String
    let legs : Int
}
its my dataModel